# Why is sympy not separating real and imaginary components

Tags: python, sympy

Using python with sympy. Trying to use only the real component, but still getting imaginary in output.

```
display(re(ns.subs(T, 1150)))
display(re(ns.subs(T, 1050)))
display(re(Z.subs(T, 1150)))
display(re(Z.subs(T, 1050)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using the exponent `0.5` instead of square root.

Let's do a simple test:

```py
print(re((-0.57 + I)**0.5))
# re((-0.57 + I)**0.5)
```

Here, the output is similar to what you get.

Let's try with `sqrt`:

```py
print(re(sqrt(-0.57 + I)))
# 0.539000466269862
```

Note that if you were to lambdify the expression (so that the evaluation is done by Numpy), then you would get the correct result:

```py
f = lambdify([], re((-0.57 + I)**0.5))
f()
# 0.5390004662698615
```

Comment: Also note that sympy isn't fond of imprecise floats such as `-0.57` and `0.5` as it tries to make exact symbolic calculations.  See [sympy's gotchas](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#two-final-notes-and) which suggest to use `S(1)/2` instead of  `0.5`.